# error in blade template syntax error, unexpected '}' - laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have method index in users controller

```
public function index()
{
    return view('users.profile')->with('title', 'ayman');
}
```

In users/profile.blade.php file:

```
<?php
 {{ $title }}
```

In route.php

```
Route::get('profile', 'users\UserController@index');
```

when run the page: http://localhost:8080/public/profile

I got this error

```
 1/1 FatalErrorException in a5c4244e0ec8b952d428220fcdcd0d45 line 2: syntax error, unexpected '}'
```

I am using Laravel 5.

may blade template not enabled?

Comment: Try without <?php tags

Comment: Thanks works. please add above as answer to mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try without `<?php` tags

I hope it helps.